# Что означает формулировка атрибута href="/" в тэге ссылки?

Tags: href

Встретил в процессе самообучения. Объяснения не нашёл. Помогите плиз.

Comment: Назад на начальную страницу

Comment: ок, спасибо, понял

Answer (score 0):

По-моему это обозначает переход в директорию по типу :

```
<a href="/html/file.html">Ссылка на сайт</a>
```

Comment: спасибо за подсказку!